# CLLocationManager not getting location without WIFI and Cellular Data

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have implemented Location module by using CLLocationManager but gets some problems.
   Getting location finely if device has WIFI or Cellular Data(3G) but when i turn both of them off. Location stop updating i mean on GPS not working.

```
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0f;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

EDIT:
Problem facing on iPhone.

Comment: Not all iOS device have GPS module.

Comment: But i'm talking about iPhone

Comment: check 'Taking Core Location Indoors' video in wwdc2014

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cellular data for GPS to work.  You don't have to have a cellular signal but the system requires that cellular data be enabled in order to allow location services.

In iOS 4 you used to be able to use location services even in Airplane Mode, by enabling Location Services in Settings after switching to Airplane mode, but this broke in iOS 5.

I've filed a bug report with Apple but they say this is how it is supposed to work now.  They try to use cellular and wifi signals triangulation to make corrections to the GPS position.

Comment: Can you please share the apple's reply.